# Reading the server name in an Nginx Ring handler working as a Proxy

Tags: java, nginx, clojure, proxy, ring

I am trying to implement a dynamic proxy using [nginx-clojure](http://nginx-clojure.github.io/).

In my nginx config file I have the following:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    jvm_path 'myjvmpath';

    jvm_var nginx_clojure_jar_path 'myNginx_clojure_jar_path';
    jvm_var my_java_handler_jar_path '...';

    jvm_options "-Djava.class.path=#{nginx_clojure_jar_path}:#{my_java_handler_jar_path}";


    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;

        location / {
            handler_type 'java'; 
            rewrite_handler_name 'com.poc.MyHandler';
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://$host$uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically with this I have all requests passing through MyHandler:

```
package com.poc;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;

import nginx.clojure.java.ArrayMap;
import nginx.clojure.java.Constants;
import nginx.clojure.java.NginxJavaRingHandler;
import static nginx.clojure.MiniConstants.*;

public class MyHandler implements NginxJavaRingHandler {

    @Override
    public Object[] invoke(Map<String, Object> request) {
        if (isRequestForbidden(request)) {
            return new Object[] { NGX_HTTP_FORBIDDEN, // http status 404
                    ArrayMap.create(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain"), // headers map
                    "Forbidden" };
        } else {
            return Constants.PHRASE_DONE;
        }
    }

    private boolean isRequestForbidden(Map<String, Object> request) {
        String serverName = (String) request.get(Constants.SERVER_NAME);
        return false;
    }

}
```

The code is trivial: based on the request(on the server name, more specifically) I want to return Constants.PHRASE_DONE(and the request will be sent to the target server) or a response indicating that site is forbidden. The problem I have is that request.get(Constants.SERVER_NAME) is returning empty string, and I was expecting to have the server name here...

Is there anything wrong with the general approach I am taking? I am a newbie with this stuff and would really appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution so I post it here.
`request.get(Constants.SERVER_NAME)` does not contain the name of the requested server but the name of the proxy server. What I was looking for is in a header with key "Host". Here is how to read it:

```
private boolean isRequestForbidden(Map<String, Object> request) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>) request
            .get(Constants.HEADERS);
    String host = headers.get("Host");

    // ...
}
```

Comment: request.get(Constants.SERVER_NAME) returns the server_name declared within the server block in nginx.conf. e.g.     server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  *.com;